# Can we fetch current location from 2nd generation Alexa device(model no:RS03QR)?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Can i fetch current location from the model i specified(echo dot model no:RS03QR)? Is there anything to do with model of alexa or every alexa device can give current location?

I enabled the location permission.But still i can't fetch the current location.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's current address information. You can view the docs [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html).

There's also an [example skill](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-node-device-address-api) in Node.js that uses the *Device Address API*.

If you are using Node.js, you might also want to check the [Node.js ASK SDK docs](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Calling-Alexa-Service-APIs.html?highlight=address#deviceaddressserviceclient). The `DeviceAddressServiceClient` is what you want.

Comment: Ya thanks .From this I managed to get the device registered address.But my requirement is to take user current location.Imagine a scenario User registered the device address in India and when the user travels to other country out of India.How can i get that location?

Comment: This is currently the only way to get any location data for the user.